# How to filter out rows where the value is very different from the other values?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr, purrr

I would like to remove rows where the value of a particular variable, `HEIGHT_CM` is very different from the other values for the same id, `PATIENT_ID`.

- Difference of >2 from the other values

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = "PATIENT_ID MEASUREMENT_TAKEN_DATE  HEIGHT_CM
1   20140305    163
1   20140409    163
1   20140528    164
1   20140730    164
1   20141210    99.7
2   20140305    155
2   20140527    157
2   20141111    78
3   20140721    90
4   20140528    168
4   20140627    167
4   20140917    167
4   20141002    70", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Desired Output**:

```
df <- read.table(text = "PATIENT_ID MEASUREMENT_TAKEN_DATE  HEIGHT_CM
1   20140305    163
1   20140409    163
1   20140528    164
1   20140730    164
2   20140305    155
2   20140527    157
3   20140721    90
4   20140528    168
4   20140627    167
4   20140917    167", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Define *very different*. Also can we see your attempt and where you got stuck?

Comment: try using `quantile()`

Comment: @Sotos Difference of >2 from the other values

Comment: Like a difference > 2 from the mean of the same id?

Comment: *"Difference of >2 from the other values "* Difference between successive entries? Difference from the mean? The median? Be specific! Also please show your code attempt!

Comment: > 2...what?  standard deviations? IQRs? Please be more specific. What method did you try to apply and where did you fail?

Comment: I don't know if I should use median or mean because the size for each id is rather small. The "outlier" would also affect the mean and median values. If I use SD, it would not work too, since I have an id that only has 1 observation. I tried to use IQR*1.5 to remove the outliers, but I still get the values that I don't wish to have.

Comment: I was wondering if there's a way in which I dont have to use any summary statistics. Like in laymen way, how do I get rid of a value which is different from the majority?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>% 
  mutate(difference = abs(mean(HEIGHT_CM, na.rm = T) - HEIGHT_CM)) %>% 
  filter(difference <= 50)
```

Here you filter for `difference >= 50`, where `difference` is between the mean of the group and the single value. This gets the output you showed us.

Answer (score 0):

A statistical way to remove outliers that gives your exact result :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>% summarize(s=sd(HEIGHT_CM),m=mean(HEIGHT_CM))
df %>% inner_join(df1,by="PATIENT_ID") %>% 
  filter(is.na(s)|((HEIGHT_CM>m-s)&(HEIGHT_CM<m+s))) %>% select(-c(4,5))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which method of removign outliers is this?

Comment: @HNSKD This is a simple classical approach. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier for more.